# How to set the nodata of Clip raster in postgis to export as tif

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to crop a raster by polygon and export as TIFF data. The problem is how to set the nodata around the polygon in the raster using psycopg2 in python, because the default value is -3.4028234663852886e+38.

I use the code:

```
 import psycopg2
 conn = psycopg2.connect(database="mydatabase",
                        user="postgres",
                        host="localhost",
                        password="postgresPass")
 cursor = conn.cursor()     

 callSaveRaster = "SELECT ST_AsTIFF(ST_UNION(ST_Clip(rast, the_geom))) as img
            from rasterSchema.rasterTable, polySchema.polyTable
            where ST_Intersects(the_geom, rast) and polyTable.gid=1";

cursor.execute(callSaveRaster)

rasterData = cursor.fetchone()

with open("raster.tif", 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write((rasterData[0]))
```

Comment: Does the original rasters, in the rasterSchema.rasterTable, have a nodata value defined?

Comment: @Pierre Yes. The problem is this rasters are Landsat images where I put ZERO for cloud regions, and I need to clip the raster by polygon and keep the zero for cloud regions inside of polygon area and set  nodata outside of region of the polygon as -1, for example. How to do that? 
If I can could to use the no

Comment: There is a ST_SetBandNoDataValue() function. You could set it before clipping: ST_Clip(ST_SetBandNoDataValue(rast, -1), the_geom)

Comment: @Pierre Amazing!! It works perfectly for first layer of the layer stack. How can I apply for all layers? I try like this ST_Clip(ST_SetBandNoDataValue(rast, [-1, -1, -1]), the_geom), but it doesn't work. At the Postgis page https://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_SetBandNoDataValue.html they propose to use multiples ST_SetBandNoDataValue(), my problem is the different number of layers for each data sample.

Comment: Good point. There is no function to set all the nodata values for all the bands of a multiband raster. Could you write one in PL/pgSQL?